# vector bundle with connection over the real line is trivial

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

there is exercise 35 in 
[here](http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/WS16/DGII/script.pdf)

> Let $M \subset \Bbb R$ be an interval and consider the vector bundle $E=M\times \Bbb R^k$, $k \in \Bbb N$, with some connection $\nabla$. Show that $(E,\nabla)$ is trivial.

I know that $(E,\nabla)$ is trivial iff there exist a parallel frame field over E. I tryed to construct such a frame field but couldn't.So how can i construct such frame field? (an example would be nice or a general way to construct such frame fields)

help would be appreciated

Comment: Hint: Use either a theorem from ODEs or the characterization of flat connections as ones with zero curvature.